# I want to get all the fields which are there in the pdf File using the PyPDF Module, gettting the error:- TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pypdf

Hi I'm trying to get all the fields which are there in the PDF file, I'm using the `PyPDF` Python module, so when I'm using the
`getFormTextFields()` method its returning the error, please Help

Below is the code which I wrote:

```
import PyPDF2

pdfFileObj = open('Trainee Application form.pdf', 'rb')
pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)


print("Pages of Document are",pdfreader.numPages)
print("The Text Fields are",pdfreader.getFormTextFields())
```

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace.

Comment: it sounds like `pdfreader` is `None` but until you include the full stack trace its hard to know. You should include the full error/stack trace in your question as it tells you where the error is happening and is needed for other people to be able to help you debug your error

Comment: You should use the ```with``` contextmanager syntax to open files

Answer (score 2):

Try [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/) to extract plain text and/or PDF "markdown" and parse then.

Here is a sample code extracting all the above from all document pages.

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(you_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

plain_text = ""
pdf_markdown = ""
try:
    while True:
        viewer.render()
        pdf_markdown += viewer.canvas.text_content
        plain_text += "".join(viewer.canvas.strings)

        #### put your parsing code here ####

        viewer.next()
except PageDoesNotExist:
    pass
```